# Cannot find file in Python flask API

Tags: python, flask

I have this decorator in Python, which has the purpose to get a file named 'api.key' in the root directory:

```
def require_appkey(view_function):
    @wraps(view_function)
    # the new, post-decoration function. Note *args and **kwargs here.
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        with open('api.key', 'r') as apikey:
            key=apikey.read().replace('\n', '')
        #if request.args.get('key') and request.args.get('key') == key:
        if request.headers.get('token_') and request.headers.get('token_') == key:
            return view_function(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return {'ERROR' : 'UNAUTHORIZED ACTION!'}
    return decorated_function
```

When executing in localhost:5000, no problems are encountered with POSTMAN but when the files are put in the AWS Ubuntu server, it returns FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'api.key'. Here is the full log:

```
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648898 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373] ERROR:flask.app:Exception on /salestracking/AuthenticateUser [POST]
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648925 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648928 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373]   File "/home/ubuntu/salesappserver/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", l$
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648931 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648934 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373]   File "/home/ubuntu/salesappserver/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", l$
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648936 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648939 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373]   File "/home/ubuntu/salesappserver/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__$
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648941 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373]     resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648943 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373]   File "/home/ubuntu/salesappserver/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/views.py",$
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648946 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373]     return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648948 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373]   File "/home/ubuntu/salesappserver/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_restful/__$
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648951 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373]     resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648953 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373]   File "/var/www/html/salesappserver/api.py", line 27, in decorated_function
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648956 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373]     with open('api.key', 'r') as apikey:
[Fri Jun 08 17:31:39.648959 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 16373] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'api.key'
```

I already check my directory and it seems that 'api.key' exists.

```
(salesappserver) ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-35:~/salesappserver$ ls
api.key  api.py  app.wsgi  bin  include  index.html  lib  pip-selfcheck.json  README.md  share
(salesappserver) ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-35:~/salesappserver$
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Could you provide the output of 'pwd' in /salesappserver ?

Comment: It doesn't have any 'pwd'.